# OpenSSL Source Outdated

Tags: ruby, rvm, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I upgraded mac os to 10.11 and want to install ruby, but when I run

```
rvm install 2.2.3
```

I got:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.1.5.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Warning: You are using OS X 10.11.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakage.
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
openssl 1.0.2c
==> Upgrading openssl
==> Downloading https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2c.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DomT4/LibreMirror/master/OpenSSL/openssl-1.0.2c.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "openssl"
Download failed: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DomT4/LibreMirror/master/OpenSSL/openssl-1.0.2c.tar.gz
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I tried to update brew, after that I upgrade it and it doesn't work

Comment: I solved it. Reinstall helps